Question about existentialists definition of absurdity

Existentialists define absurdity as the search for answers in an
answerless world. It’s the idea of being born into a meaningless place
that then requires you to make meaning.
The absurd posits there is no one truth, no inherent rules or
guidelines. This means you have to develop your own moral code to live
by. Sartre cautioned looking to authority for guidance and answers
because no one has them and there is no one truth.
Coined by Jean-Paul Sartre, the phrase “living authentically” means to
live with the understanding of your responsibility to control your
freedom despite the absurd. Any purpose or meaning in your life is
created by you.
If you choose to live by someone else’s rules, be that anywhere
between religion and the wishes of your parents, then you are refusing
to accept the absurd. Jean-Paul Sartre named this refusal “bad faith”,
as you are choosing to live by someone else’s definition of meaning
and purpose – not your own.
“Man is condemned to be free; because once thrown into the world, he
is responsible for everything he does” – John-Paul Sartre Freedom is
usually presented positively but Sartre posed that your level of
freedom is so great it’s “painful”. To fully comprehend your freedom,
you have to accept that only you are responsible for creating or
failing to create your personal purpose. Without rules or order to
guide you, you have so much choice that freedom is overwhelming.
While not necessarily atheist, existentialists believe there is no
divine intervention, fate or outside forces actively pushing you in
particular directions. Every decision you make is yours. You create
your own purpose through your actions.

=================

Essentialism was founded by the Greek philosopher Aristotle.  This idea
seems to imply, whether you’re aware of it or not, that your purpose
in life has been determined prior to your birth. And as you live your
life, the decisions you make on a daily basis are contributing to your
ultimate purpose, whatever that happens to be.

https://ethics.org.au/ethics-explainer-existentialism/
My question is how this theoretical and literal 'absurdity' became mainstream thinking in the modern world?
In my personal view, it is so sad to think that you are coming from nowhere and going to nothing.

RE: "it is so sad..." I think, almost by definition, nobody is "happy" about the absurd; the whole point is "we are driven to look for meaning in life, but there doesn't appear to be any". One doesn't look for meaning in life without wishing one could find it.

"but there doesn't appear to be any" - Again, this is my personal view. But my impression is that you can only come to this conclusion if you are not familiar with the best of literature, poetry and philosophy in human heritage.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance maybe to make this more specific, what's some piece of literature/poetry/philosophy you think makes a strong case for a particular inherent meaning in life?

@Kaia - it is in my question: "Aristotle seems to imply, whether you’re aware of it or not, that your purpose in life has been determined prior to your birth. "

“In my view, it is so sad to think that you are coming from nowhere and going to nothing.” - some people find that liberating, some people don’t care. The existence of a purpose at all is questionable, if not veritably false. And like Lowri said - is such absurdity mainstream? Aristotle said a lot of pretty weird things (as well as some very insightful things)…

Semantic frame challenge: '"existentialists define absurdity as" is wrong, since there are many other things existentialists may find absurd, and not everyone would describe it that way If you want to say that existentialists commonly consider X absurd, fine, but it is not the definition of the word nor a universal opinion. It's also an unnecessarily loaded term.

@keshlam I think "the absurd" or "the absurd state" is often the term used for that and I don't think it's "loaded" in this context so much as a technical term being used in a narrow sense

Any existentialists here to confirm @kaia's usage? If so, perhaps the question could clarify that only this jargon usage is referenced, and arguably mark it visually in every use to reinforce that. I'm suspicious any time I heard someone assert claims about someone else's beliefs and practices.

Existentialists use the term absurdity to suggest that it's silly and presumptive to think that life comes pre-equipped with meaning, as though our life were an Ikea kit that we bang together using the provided tools and pictographic instructions. For existentialists we don't receive meaning or find meaning; we make meaning. The danger the existentialists see is that we might forget that we made our meanings, and fall into the trap of thinking we received or found them. Once we fall into that trap, we begin to sacrifice accountability and moral integrity because we place accountability and moral integrity on the external source where we believe we found or received our meanings.
It's absurd because we have to we have to accept our meanings as de facto truths at the same time that we know our meanings are self-fabricated.
Keep in mind that existentialism developed through the first and second world wars, where philosophers not only saw the creation of vast and dehumanized forms of destruction (ways of destroying masses of people at long distances), but also the rise of mass propaganda, identity nationalism, state security apparatuses, spy-craft and disinformation, and a general (and often vicious) effort to contain and control narratives for political gain. To their minds, the act of placing accountability and moral integrity on external sources led directly to brutal warfare and genocide; external sources could not be trusted to be accountable or morally sound. The only solution (for the existentialists) was to kick off any received or found meanings as untrustworthy, and then dig back in and create (or recreate) meaning independently, with our own sense of accountability and our own moral uprightness.
Existentialism strikes me as a bit of a 'hair shirt' philosophical school, which is understandable given its context. But it is a sound and sobering perspective. Even if we adopt an external set of meanings (from a religion, an identity group, a culture), we have to be aware that we are making a decision to adopt them, and that we are morally responsible for the consequences they bring. We don't want to be the one passing out that 'special KoolAid' to our friends and family because the revered leader told us it was good and right to do so.

What do you mean by "hair shirt"?

They're itchy but warm, army issue. https://handwovenmagazine.com/history-hairshirts/

"Ted Wrigley" - I agree with your explanation. You seem to put Existentialism at the margins. But how then to reconcile with: "Physicalism generally does not accept Existentialism because physicalism asserts that everything is fundamentally physical, while Existentialism emphasizes the freedom and unique nature of human existence, often suggesting a level of non-physical agency that contradicts the physicalist view"

@kaia: 'Hair shirt' means extremely austere. Hair shirts were worn by some Christian penitents  to show their dedication; the discomfort and ugliness of such shirts proved the penitent's sincerity. I just mean it here to suggest existentialists tended to push the concept to an uncomfortable and uncompromising extreme

@TheMatrixEquation-balance: It seems to me you've answered your own comment. Existentialism is a moral philosophy as much as a philosophy of being, and physicalism has definite difficulties incorporating or meshing with any moral philosophy. Physicalism denies agency; moral philosophy demands it.

Either I'm not a physicalist, or physicalism does not deny agency. Despite what dualists may believe.

@keshlam: Well, the problem is that agency is non-deterministic by definition. I don't know of a version of physicalism that allows non-deterministism (and thus allows agency), but I can't say I know everything there is to know about physicalism.  How would you account for that?

@TedWrigley: Quantum physics is pretty damned non-deterministic. We assume the rest of the universe builds up from that base, and in fact we have demonstrated quantum effects in macroscopic objects, and we assume that macroscopic properties are the results of the statistical accumulation of those. Until you can show determinism at the quantum level, I believe that there is enough randomness to make the macroscopic universe non-deterministic. You are welcome to disagree. Deterministically or non-deterministically, I'm content with my answer.

If you want to argue that quantum physics is deterministic at a level we haven't figured out yet, that's perfectly possible. If that happens, I may have to concede that the universe is deterministic, which might deny free will if you want to get down to that layer. Since it doesn't feel like it is, I'm not sure I care, but there you are. I'm an engineer; I care more about whether the model works than whether it is absolute Truth, and for all practical purposes short of the metaphysical there is no question about whether we have free will.

OP: "In my personal view, it is so sad to think that you are coming from nowhere and going to nothing."
How about God leaves you free to determine your own meaning? No great leader, parent or purpose ruling your life. You are free to determine for yourself what is meaningful in the culture you find yourself in. What makes sense and gives you satisfaction in accomplishing – all your own. The beginning of a great adventure.
What Sartre calls absurdity is what Heidegger – who Sartre rips-off wholesale – called 'inauthenticity'. This is the givenness-over to one's group, which is our starting state. One has to find one's authenticity, and the call of conscience is a decisive factor in this.

Bingo. Your personal view is not everyone's view. Leave space for honest disagreement.

@keshlam I am very open to consider other positions.

Sorry, I should have said the original poster's view, etc. This may have been an unnecessary comment, but I wanted to endorse your point with a bit more than an up vote. (Perhaps I should have said "a" rather than "your".)

What bothers me the most is the attempt to paint our reality in black and white. There is free choice / there is not. There is God / there is not. There is an external influence on your life / or there is not.  Real wisdom (including philosophy) is always in a gray area, never absolutely confident or conclusive.

Yup. No one else can judge what you do.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance The postmodernists fuzz'd things up good 'n proper, so it's kind of a given that these paintings are shadow-play. (But I was already focusing on indeterminacy so a bit more fuzz made no difference.)
